# Next Auth - auto sign in after sign up

Tags: reactjs, authentication, next.js, next-auth

I couldn't find any docs about automatic sign in a user who has just signed up.
The only way I could think of is one user has been signed up, then programmatically call signIn function provided by next-auth to log him in.

is there any other way to do it? not sure its best practice

thanks

Answer (score 5):

You can use "Sign in callback" after sign up.

```
const response = await fetch("/api/register", {
      method: "POST",
      body: JSON.stringify(values),
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
      },
    })
    if (response.ok) {
      await signIn("credentials", {
        email: values.email,
        password: values.password,
        redirect: true,
        callbackUrl: "/",
      })
    }
```